# Insertion Sort Wrong output

Tags: java, algorithm

I have implemented a insertion Sort algorithm and when i display the array wrong output will be displayed.

```
public void insertionSort()
    {
        int[] arr=new int[]{34,54,12,32};

        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            int key=arr[i];
            int hole=i-1;

            while(hole>=0 && key<arr[hole])
            {
                arr[i+1]=arr[i];
                 hole-=1;
            }
            arr[hole+1]=key;
        }
        display(arr);

    }

  public void display(int[] dis)
    {
        Arrays.stream(dis).forEach(v->System.out.print(v+"\t"));
    }
```

**output**

```
12  54  12  12
```

i could not find what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions needs to be changed for the while loop : You were modifying on `i` rather u should modify on `hole`

**Full Code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr=new int[]{34,54,12,32};
        System.out.println("Original Array");
        display(arr);
        System.out.println("\nAfter Insertion Sort");
        insertionSort(arr);
        display(arr);
    }
    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
            int key=arr[i];
            int hole=i-1;

            while(hole>=0 && arr[hole]>key) {
                arr[hole+1]=arr[hole];
                 hole-=1;
            }
            arr[hole+1]=key;
        }
    }

    public static void display(int[] dis)  {
        Arrays.stream(dis).forEach(v->System.out.print(v+"\t"));
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Original Array                                                                                                                                                
34      54      12      32                                                                                                                                    
After Insertion Sort                                                                                                                                          
12      32      34      54
```